# Play Video By Physical location in C# XAML Windows Store Apps

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

I am a new bee to develop windows store apps, I had a scenario like I have to play a video based on physical location.

If video present in the project, I know how to set source to Media Element and play it.

Here my scenario is to play video, where I have is its physical location.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Raghu.M.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your list is less than hundreds of files - it might be worth keeping the `StorageFile` objects returned from the file open picker. Otherwise - you should get and store [future access tokens](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.accesscache.storageapplicationpermissions.futureaccesslist.aspx) from the files for later use. You can't open files outside of the safe zones unless the user has picked one with the picker dialog and either you still have the `StorageFile` object itself or the future access token that you reserved when that first happened.

Comment: Thanks this is what I implemented. Anyway thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Use `OpenFilePicker`

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var openPicker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker();
        openPicker.ViewMode = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
        openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.VideosLibrary;

        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".wmv");
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mp4");
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".wma");
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mp3");

        var file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();

        if (file != null)
        {
            var stream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);

            mediaElement.SetSource(stream, file.ContentType);
            mediaElement.Play();
        }
    }
```

Comment: this is not the case, I already had open file picker in other window, and user selects some videos, I make list of those videos (I have physical location of that video) and display a list, but when user click on any video of that list I need to play that particular video using physical location.